# How to run java code with Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant

Here is a part of my **build.xml**:

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${Main.class}.jar" 
        fork="yes"
        <assertions>
            <enable />
        </assertions>
    </java>
</target>
```

or

```
<target name="run">
    <java classname="${Main.class}" classpath="${classes.dir};${lib.dir}" fork="yes"/>
</target>
```

---

Here is an example **java code**:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        System.out.print("Test2");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        new Test();
        while(true) {}
    }
}
```

---

If I run this code from command line I have "Test1" and then "Test2".
If I run this code using the Ant I have only "Test1".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably find that Ant buffers the output to `System.out` of your program by line before printing to stdout, and because your program never terminates (the `while (true) {}`), Ant is waiting for the program to finish before flushing the output of the line.  Try changing the `Test` constructor to use `println` and you'll see the output.

Comment: Yeap, I see that. But how can repair it? It's only an example, but I need to use exactly "System.out.print".

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem.

```
System.out.flush();
```

Add it before you get into an infinite loop. (EDIT:) and after you call new Test()